# There are any server I can run my dynamic web project on it?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server

I am using tomcat server on eclipse java EE ,  but suddenly the server not execute my dynamic  web project  ( my project was run fine on server and suddenly the tomcat did not run my project )... I try a lot to solve the problem  But I faild ... so there are another server can I use it on jsp ?

Comment: What's the error ? If you've messed up your app it won't run on any server

Comment: No error appare I am using codemirror with my project ... it was worked fine ... and suddenly the specific code I write related on codemirror mirror not excute .... I search on codemirror But no body have problem on use it

Comment: check the server logs - catalina.out

Comment: Where I can find Catalina.out ?

Comment: in the `/logs` folder of your tomcat installation

Comment: I did not find it in /logs folder of my tomcat installation. .. it is empty

Comment: Is the problem because it not found on my tomcat installation?

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: Then try from eclipse -> on the "servers" view, select your server and then "view logs"

Comment: I Google it ... the Catalina.out not found in windows user ... but I did not find how to fix it